# Submenus In Bootstrap 3 Adding Click Open Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create submenus within Bootstrap 3 (which we all know have been removed) and I would like to display the 2nd and 3rd levels of the menu on a click instead of a hover.

For some reason every time I click on 2nd level or third level it simply closes the dropdown menu as if it is toggling the regular bootstrap open/close function.

I need to work in a manor...
1.) Click on Top level - display down-drop items
2.) Click on item from drop-down - displays 2nd level items
3.) Click on item from 2nd level - displays 3rd level items

basically i want to activate this css class

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}
```

on a click instead of a hover.

Currently i have tried the following

Link To Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Tenacity/ejLDg/1/

Preferably can you should your solution on the fiddle.  Feel free to rip this entire example apart to achieve a solution as i'm completely stuck.  Thanks in advance.

The HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Your Logo Here</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">           
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="test1">Top Level <b class="caret"></b></a>         
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">



                 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">To 2nd</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#">2nd to 3rd</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </li>          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

The CSS

```
.dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
```

The JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.dropdown-submenu').on('click', function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass('open');
   $(".btn-navbar").click();
   alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Why don't you try to change css style by using JS? Try this.   $('.dropdown-submenu').click(function(){
   $('.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
  return false;
});

Answer (score 8, accepted):

take a look:

```
$( ".dropdown-submenu" ).click(function(event) {
    // stop bootstrap.js to hide the parents
    event.stopPropagation();
    // hide the open children
    $( this ).find(".dropdown-submenu").removeClass('open');
    // add 'open' class to all parents with class 'dropdown-submenu'
    $( this ).parents(".dropdown-submenu").addClass('open');
    // this is also open (or was)
    $( this ).toggleClass('open');
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ejLDg/18/**

Comment: This worked very well and extremely efficient. The parent selector was key.  Thanks great work.

Comment: Quick question I noticed that if the user click open a few menus then clicks outside of the nav menu (which activates the close function)  then if you go back to the menu item all the levels of the menu are still open is there some way to apply your fix for removing the classes to all levels of the menu if the user clicks outside the screen?  Thanks again

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ejLDg/23/.
you can read the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage
Using in the event `hidden.bs.dropdown` - (When the dropdown hidden)

Comment: this doesn't hide the opened sub-menu when clicking other sub-menu **check better one** [here](http://www.bootply.com/97919), hope helps someone.

Comment: Thanks @stom ... Initially that link wouldn't come up for me (although it did later), but also found it on the Wayback Machine (Internet Archive): https://web.archive.org/web/20160507042157/http://www.bootply.com/97919